# How to get & decode messages destinated to a specific port

Tags: python, sockets, networking, decode, packet

I'm currently working with a particular system where a set of machines sends a message (a picture to be more precise) to a server (mainly for storage purposes) when a certain triggering event occurs (real-time).
*These pictures are also stored locally in each equipment.*

I decided to adventure myself in finding an alternative to this server, just for educational purpose. I made a Python script that accesses each machine every 15 minutes through SSH and with the use of SCP it downloads the latest pictures to my workstation.

I'm happy with this solution but I would like to also implement a way to get those pictures in a real-time fashion. So, I'm thinking about activating 'port mirroring' @ the switch where the server machine is connected to and make a Python script to decode the packets and download the pictures.
*Basically I would have my Workstation connected to a switch port that receives all the traffic coming to the server machine.*

**Does anyone have an idea of how to decode these packets to get the pictures?**
**How can one decode messages coming from the switch port?**
Using the *netstat* command on CMD I might be able to get the port that identifies the server process - maybe that's a start, right?

Is it possible to use WireShark to see what's the payload format and from there try to reverse engineer the pictures?

Please let me know of any approach you might know and/or find interesting to try.

Thank you.

Comment: This depends on the application protocol used to transfer the pictures. HTTP - likely possible, HTTPS - very likely impossible since it is encrypted, other protocols - it depends.

Comment: Rolling out the welcome mat - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To add to Steffen's comment, decrypting files transferred over HTTPS is actually possible *IF* you can save the TLS keys AND your client/server software is capable of this. See [this article](https://tshark.dev/export/export_tls/) for more info.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the response. 

I would like to clarify the following:
I have a script that gets all the pictures from every machine through SSH connection (+ SCP).

However, I would like to abandon this approach.  

What I want is to: 
- Have my workstation connected to a physical port of the Switch 
(where the server machine is connected to) 

- Receive a copy of all traffic flowing from the Machines-->Server.

- Have a python script on my WKS that listens to incoming traffic directed to the servers process port & decode those messages in order to get the pictures.

Comment: You would be much better to replace the server with a reliable implementation - then you aren’t doing dodgy things like trying to decrypt passing SSL traffic, and you completely avoid the problem because your replacement server would be outside the encrypted flow.

Comment: @barny I totally agree, but I'm trying to do this more on an educational manner - just to learn a bit more about how things work. Thank you!

Comment: Switches only send frames to the destination interface, not all the interfaces, so a device connected to a different switch interface would never see the traffic. _Some_ enterprise-grade switches can be configured to mirror traffic to a particular interface, but that depends on the manufacturer and model, and it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Can SSH traffic be decrypted *ex post facto* with Wireshark?

No, you cannot [Man-in-the-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) SSH-encrypted packets if all you have is a capture from a port-mirror. This is unless you are the NSA or nation-state actor and have found a way to circumvent the encryption.

> Does anyone have an idea of how to decode these packets to get the pictures?

Even if you could decrypt SSH (see below), it is not possible to do this with Wireshark. Per the Wireshark [docs on SSH](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSH):

> Unlike the SSL dissector, no code has been written to decrypt encrypted SSH packets/payload.

### Can Wireshark detect file metadata in encrypted traffic?

> Is it possible to use WireShark to see what's the payload format and from there try to reverse engineer the pictures?

No it's encrypted - you can't see anything. The most you will be able to see is SSH setup messages.

### Alternatives

If you have access to client/server and set this up beforehand, there are [solutions](https://github.com/trolldbois/sslsnoop) to extract the secret keys from memory. Keep in mind that you MUST have this set up beforehand on client or server as these session keys expire with the session (depending on the protocol).